# Read file of repeated "key=value" pairs into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file with data in this format.  The first 3 lines repeat over and over.

```
name=1
grade=A
class=B
name=2
grade=D
class=A
```

I would like to output the data in a table format, for example:

```
name | grade | class
1    | A     | B
2    | D     | A
```

I am struggling to set the headers and just loop over the data.  What I have tried so far is:

```
def myfile(filename):
    with open(file1) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip().split('=',1)

def pprint_df(dframe):
    print(tabulate(dframe, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False,))

#f = pd.DataFrame(myfile('file1')
df = pd.DataFrame(myfile('file1'))
pprint_df(df)
```

The output from that is

```
+-------+-----+
| 0     | 1   |
|-------+-----|
| name  | 1   |
| grade | A   |
| class | B   |
| name  | 2   |
| grade | D   |
| class | A   |
+-------+-----+
```

Not really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution assumes the text format is as you have described, but you could modify it to use a different word to denote the beginning of a new line. Here, we assume that a new line starts with the `name` field. I've modified your `myfile()` function below, hope it gives you some ideas :)

```
def myfile(filename):
    d_list = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        d_line = {}
        for line in f:
            split_line = line.rstrip("\n").split('=')  # Strip \n characters and split field and value.
            if (split_line[0] == 'name'):
                if d_line:
                    d_list.append(d_line)  # Append if there is previous line in d_line.
                d_line = {split_line[0]: split_line[1]}  # Start a new dictionary to collect the next lines.
            else:
                d_line[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]  # Add the other 2 fields to the dictionary.
        d_list.append(d_line) # Append the last line.
    return pd.DataFrame(d_list)  # Turn the list of dictionaries into a DataFrame.
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use pandas to read the file and process the data. You may use this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(r'file.txt', header=None)
new = df[0].str.split("=", n=1, expand=True)
new['index'] = new.groupby(new[0])[0].cumcount()
new = new.pivot(index='index', columns=0, values=1)
```

`new` Outputs:

```
0     class grade name
index                 
0         B     A    1
1         A     D    2
```

Comment: add `df = pd.read_table(file, header=None)`, make the following line `new = df[0].str.split("=", n=1, expand=True)`, and this would be my favorite answer in terms of "nice code".

Comment: +1 ;-) however, I just ran a `%timeit` against my answer and was supriesed how slow the pure-pandas solution is. It was about x7 slower on my machine (for a very small input txt file)! With convenience comes overhead, with overhead (most of the time) comes loss in performance...

Answer (score 7):

I know you have enough answers, but here is another way of doing it using dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

with open("text_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split('=')
        d[key].append(val.replace('\n', ''))

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

This gives you the output as:

```
name grade class
0    1     A     B
1    2     D     A
```

Just to get another perspective.

Answer (score 3):

What you could also do is read your textfile `file` in blocks of 3, build a nested list, and put that in a dataframe:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
import pandas as pd

# taken from https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html:
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

data = [['name', 'grade', 'class']]
with open(file, 'r') as fobj:
    blocks = grouper(fobj, 3)
    for b in blocks:
        data.append([i.split('=')[-1].strip() for i in b])

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

`df` would directly be

```
  name grade class
0    1     A     B
1    2     D     A
```

**Note #1:** Although this makes for more lines of code than a pure `pandas` solution, in my experience it is likely to be more efficient since it uses less `pandas` functions thus less overhead.

**Note #2:** In general I would argue that it would be better to store your input data in another format, e.g. `json` or `csv`. that would make it much more easy to read, for example with the `pandas` function [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in case of a csv file.

Answer (score 3):

As you've got an output this is how I would deal with the problem :

First create a unique index based on the repeatability of the columns,

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby(df['0'])['0'].cumcount() + 1
print(df)
        0  1  idx
0   name  1      1
1  grade  A      1
2  class  B      1
3   name  2      2
4  grade  D      2
5  class  A      2
```

we then use this to pivot your dataframe using the `crosstab` function

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['idx'],df['0'],values=df['1'],aggfunc='first').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1[['name','grade','class']])
0 name grade class
0    1     A     B
1    2     D     A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate that output by using **Python's Dictionary module** and Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

text = '''name=1
          grade=A
          class=B
          name=2
          grade=D
          class=A'''
text = text.split()

new_dict = defaultdict(list) 
for i in text:
    temp = i.split('=')
    new_dict[temp[0]].append(temp[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
```

This approach might not be the most efficient one but it doesn't use any of the advanced functions of Pandas. Hope it helps.

The output:

```
    name    grade   class
0      1        A       B
1      2        D       A
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, all current answers look too complicated. What I would do, is to use `'='` as a `sep` parameter of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read 2 columns, and then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the obtained DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile', sep='=', header=None)
#        0  1
# 0   name  1
# 1  grade  A
# 2  class  B
# 3   name  2
# 4  grade  D
# 5  class  A

df = df.pivot(index=df.index // len(df[0].unique()), columns=0)
#       1           
# 0 class grade name
# 0     B     A    1
# 1     A     D    2
```

If you don't want that multi-level column index in the result, you can remove it by:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
# 0 class grade name
# 0     B     A    1
# 1     A     D    2
```